# Hierarchy in HTML form elements and POSTed data

Tags: html, forms, post

Is there any known issue or drawback for naming from elements like this:

```
<form method="POST" ... >
    <input name="category[title]" ...>
    <input name="category[desc]" ...>
</form>
```

The `POST` result will be something like this:

```
Array 
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [title] => 0
            [desc] => 0
        )
)
```

Does it work in all the major web browsers? Also is there any specific name for it?

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Check it:

```js
/* send a object like it:
Person:
{
 name: 'Homer'
 age : 50
 kids :[
  { name: 'Liza', age: 9 }, 
  { name: 'Bart', age: 8 }, 
  {name: 'Maggie', age: 2 }
 ]}
 */
```

```html
<form method="post" action='my_magic_form.xpto'>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Your age" />
    <input type="text" name="kids[0].name" placeholder="First child name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="kids[0].age" placeholder="First child age" />
    <input type="text" name="kids[1].name" placeholder="Second child name" />
    <input type="text" name="kids[1].age" placeholder="Second child age" /> 
    <input type="text" name="kids[2].name" placeholder="Third child name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="kids[2].age" placeholder="Third child age" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! What's that `.xpto` in the form action?