# how to send multiple values for single name through forms?

Tags: php, html

Here is index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="C" />:C
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="C++"/>:C++
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="java"/>:JAVA
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="python"/>:PYTHON
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="none"/>:None
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my process.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <?php
        print_r($_POST);
        ?>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are in same folder. In these php pages i am trying to show the content of data send through index.php form.
But it only shows the last clicked checkbox. For example if i have checked C++ and JAVA then it will only show JAVA all preceding will be kicked off. Since checkbox are made for multiple checks why not it just show it as array(values)? 
I want to know how to get multiple values for single name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML input arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You can send multiple values by adding `[]` to the end of the name. It will convert into an array on php side.

```
name="language[]"
```