# Looping PHP with Checkbox

Tags: php, for-loop

Please Help Me.

I have `form=myform` like this

```
<form name='myform' method='post' action='update.php'>  
                  <div id='add-new-button' style='padding:9px;'>

                  <input type='submit' name='pilih' value='Update' ></div>
                  <div class='tbl_sp'> 

          <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='table-detail'><thead >
          <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Custname</th>
          </tr></thead><tbody>";
          $counter = 1;
$query= mssql_query("SELECT top 10 * from Customer ");

$f=1;
while ($r=mssql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if (is_float($counter/2)) {$class = "class='alt'"; } else { $class = ""; };

    echo"<tr $class>
<td><input type='hidden' name='data".$f."' value='".$r['No']."' />$r[tNo]</td>
<td>$r[CustName]</td>
</tr>


    "; $f++;
          $counter++;  
          }
echo"</tbody></table><input type='hidden' name='m' value='".$f."' /></div><div class='center'>
          <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='table-detail'><thead >
          <tr>
          <th>Check</th>
          <th>Tools</th>
          </tr></thead><tbody>";
          $counter = 1;
$query= mssql_query("SELECT  * from tools");

$g=1;
while ($r=mssql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if (is_float($counter/2)) {$class = "class='alt'"; } else { $class = ""; };

    echo"<tr $class>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='id".$g."' value='".$r['tools']."' /></td>
<td>$r[tools]</td>
</tr>


    "; $g++;
          $counter++;  
          }";

</div>";
echo"</tbody></table></form><input type='hidden' name='n' value='".$g."' /> </div>";
}}
```

results
[image]

after form action update.php with code like this

```
    $tools_total = 0;
$customer_total = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

  if (strpos($key, 'data') === 0) {
    $customer_total++;            //getting total number of checked customers
  }
  if (strpos($key, 'id') === 0) {
    $tools_total++;               //getting total number of tools
  }
}

$k=1;
for($i=1; $i<=$customer_total; $i++)
{

    ($k>$tools_total)?$k=1:''; //reset tools counter

    //This if statement is not necessary, since I'm guessing
    //your $_POST['m'] and $_POST['n'] are giving you the total set values.
    if (isset($_POST['id'.$k]) && isset($_POST['data'.$i])){ 
        $data=$_POST['data'.$i];
        $ini=$_POST['id'.$k];
        echo " tools ='$ini'  and customer='$data' <br>\n";
    }

    $k++;
}
```

How to code with results like this.

```
tools ='AB'and Customer='1'     
tools ='AC'and Customer='2'     
tools ='AB'and Customer='3'
```

Note:

```
$_POST['m'] = count customer
$_POST['n'] = count tools
```

Table customer (Count=10) Table Tools (Count=20)
Description:
if I Check table Tools
then table customer will set to table tools that in check.
example:
I Check Tools AB and AC
and results must be:

```
tools AB and customer 1 
tools AC and customer 2 
tools AB and customer 3 
tools AC and customer 4 
tools AB and customer 5 
tools AC and customer 6
tools AB and customer 7
tools AC and customer 8 
tools AB and customer 9 
tools AC and customer 10
```

Comment: you're looping on both counts, but only ever check if `id$k` exists. Shouldn't you check if `data$i` exists as well?

Comment: So if I'm right, you want each `customer` to be allotted to each `tool` in sequence, and when the last `tool` is reached, you want to start from the first `tool` again till the end of `customer`?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Check Edited Post Below
/*
$tools_total = 0;
$customer_total = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($key, 'data') === 0) {
    $customer_total++;            //getting total number of checked customers
  }
  if (strpos($key, 'id') === 0) {
    $tools_total++;               //getting total number of checked tools
  }
}

$k=1;
for($i=1; $i<=$customer_total; $i++)
{

    ($k>$tools_total)?$k=1:''; //reset tools counter

    if (isset($_POST['id'.$k]) && isset($_POST['data'.$i])){ 
        $data=$_POST['data'.$i];
        $ini=$_POST['id'.$k];
        echo " tools ='$ini'  and customer='$data' <br>\n";
    }

    $k++;
}
*/
```

## Edited post:

Change your HTML of data input tag to:

```
<input type='hidden' name='data[]' value='".$r['No']."' />
```

Change your HTML of id input tag to:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='".$r['tools']."' />
```

Now your PHP code to:

```
$tools_total = count($_POST['id']);

$k=0;
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key=>$val){
    ($k>($tools_total-1))?$k=0:''; //reset tools counter
    $data=$val;
    $ini=$_POST['id'][$k];
    echo " tools ='$ini'  and customer='$data' <br>\n";
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: the Script is work but Not The Results tools ='AB'and Customer='1'     
tools ='AC'and Customer='2'     
tools ='AB'and Customer='3'

Comment: Please be clear. Is that the result you see or the result you need? If that's what you need, what do you see as output?

Comment: I didn't quite get that, may I know what output the above code gives?

Comment: i Edit My Question. The Output your script if i check table user value 3 then in table customer output value 3

Comment: @user3300597 I really don't understand where you're stuck. I take it the output in your edited question is the one you actually need, so can I know what output you are receiving with the above written code?

Comment: @user3300597 Can I know the value of `$_POST['n']`?

Comment: $_POST['n'] = Count 30 tools and $_POST['m']= Count 100 customer

Comment: `$_POST['n']` and `$_POST['m']` are the number of tools and customers you have checked, correct? Can I see the code of how you are setting these values?

Comment: @user3300597 Can you try my updated code and see if it works like you needed?

Comment: No. $_POST['n'] and $_POST['m'] is total count.How can I sent u code php?

Comment: Ms.* Does it show you any output at all? Can you `var_dump($_POST);` and paste it here? Also `echo $tools_total; echo $customer_total;` after the `foreach` and paste here please.

Comment: very hard Description Mr.

Comment: I'll give up if you're not being cooperative. Can you please try the code in the above comment and paste the output here?

Comment: I will cooperative Mr. the output (0
0
0
0
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
6
0
7
0
8
0
9
0
10
0
10
0
10
0
10
0
10
1
10
2
10 )

Comment: So I think `2` is the `$tools_total` and `10` is `$customer_total` Now can you please paste the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?  I know it's difficult to paste into comments but you do not have enough reputation for me to open a chat page.

Comment: Yups I don't have reputataion because I newbie.where I Paste var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: 2 is total tool checked.and 10 is total customer.

Comment: @user3300597 You can edit your question and paste your `$_POST` details. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @user3300597 I had asked you to `var_dump($_POST);` and paste the results which you didn't. Also I don't want to make massive loads of comment here having to repeat myself several times.

Comment: the results var_dump($_POST):array(18) { ["pilih"]=> string(6) "Update" ["data1"]=> string(9) "1" ["data2"]=> 
string(9) "2" ["data3"]=> string(9) "3" ["data4"]=> string(9) "4" 
["data5"]=> string(9) "5" ["data6"]=> string(9) "6" ["data7"]=> string(9) 
"100113515" ["data8"]=> string(9) "100113519" ["data9"]=> string(9) "100113531" ["data10"]=> string(9) 
"200413884" ["m"]=> string(2) "11" ["tanggal"]=> string(19) "2014-02-18 17:02:11" ["user"]=> string(7) 
"tes" ["status"]=> string(0) "" ["id11"]=> string(5) "AB" ["id12"]=> string(3) "AC" ["n"]=> string(2) "34" }

Comment: @user3300597 Please check the updated post. Whenever you have multiple inputs using similar name, use [input arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays) , they are easier to manage than custom counters.