# how to correct writing on local storage where the input type is an array of radio

Tags: php, mysql

my code

```
<form method="post" name="frm">
Question 1
<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="a"> A
<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="b"> B
<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="c"> C
<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="d"> D
Question 2
<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="a"> A
<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="b"> B
<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="c"> C
<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="d"> D
</form>
```

why i use local storage ?, because this is actually a form pagination.

when i try this

```
localStorage.setItem('Text',$('input[name="answer[]"]:checked').val());
```

it says undefined.

so, how to correct writing when the input type is an array of radio?.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[name*="answer"]:checked').val()
```

To get all input with name containing "answer".

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer.
When i try your code, it just show value of name='answer[0]'

Comment: May be since that is the only one checked

Comment: If you want all use $('input[name*="answer"]').val()

Comment: $('input[name*="answer"]:checked') will be an array. You can use $('input[name*="answer"]:checked')[0] $('input[name*="answer"]:checked')[1] etc

Comment: To get value $('input[name*="answer"]:checked')[0].value $('input[name*="answer"]:checked')[1].value

Comment: yes it show, but i think "Text" must be array to, but how to add array, should i use this localStorage.setItem('Text'.[0],$('input[name*="answer"]:checked')[0].value) ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure , but you can't name an input with an index of array .

all of you input from question 1 should be named answer1 and all of your question 2 inputs should be named answer2 , this way you ll get your correct values in jQuery.

It s not jQuery related but HTML.

[HTML input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)