# PHP Variable variables when saving to database

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have a `save.php` page that is being called using Ajax, it contains the following elements:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q1"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q3 = $_POST["q3"];
$q4 = $_POST["q4"];
$q5 = $_POST["q5"];

$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults 
(respondent_id, ip, browser, company, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "issiiiii", 
$respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $company, 
$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
```

At the moment, the `save.php` page is manually coded but I am sure there must be a way of using `variable variables` to automate this page to a degree, especially when the number of fields exceeds 100 that I am saving to the database.

I am, however, having trouble getting my head around using `variable variables` and could use some guidance.

I am have, to no avail, tried the following:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo '$q.$i = $_POST["q".$i];';
}
```

and also

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $q.$i = $_POST["q".$i];
}
```

Any and all advice welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: `${'q'.$i} = $_POST['q'.$i];`

Comment: `$var = "q$i"; $$var = $_POST[$var];`.  But seriously, look into naming  your form fields better.

Comment: Even if you do this, I guess there will be a scope issue since they are being declared inside the loop, I suggest you name your fields as `q[]` that way the system auto-indexes your fields and you can loop through them easy.

Comment: Yeah, what he said.  :)

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz - thanks for the feedback - do you have any further information you can point me too?

Comment: @Homer_J Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1010970/2513523). It's using a checkbox but the same can be implemented for any other input/select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
${'q'.$i} = $_POST['q'.$i];
```

Also:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo '$q.$i = $_POST["q".$i];';
}
```

should be:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "$q.$i = $_POST['q'.$i];";
    //   ^                       ^
}
```

otherwise variables won't be interpolated within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in `{}` like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
${'q'.$i}=$_POST['q'.$i];
}
```

Please got through this once for reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @Jefffrey..sorry I didn't see your answer while I was posting this.