# What does nested bracket mean in jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example

```
$('input[name="form[some_ids]"]')
```

What does the inner bracket represents?

Comment: They're not interpreted specially. They're just characters to be looked for in the "name" attribute of elements.

Comment: @Pointy great answer! :)

Comment: For a little bit more clarity, the selector could be `$('input[name="form[()!]4#"]')` and it wouldn't make a difference. anything inside the `""` for name is simply a string. The reason the brackets will be there is that the field will have it's name attribute set as such so a backend programming language can interpret the resulting output as an array (e.g. in php you could access `$_POST['form']['some_ids']` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Pointy, it will match something like this.

```
<input name="form[some_ids]" />
```

The inner bracket is not part of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The inner bracket usually repesents an input array. Here's a link that explains it a bit:

[HTML input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)