# How I can get multiple textbox value by foreach in php

Tags: php

Hello can you please help that how i can get description by this loop ?

```
$timepicker = $_POST['timepicker']; 
$discription = $_POST['description'];
foreach( $timepicker as $key => $n ) 
{
print "".$n." ".$discription[$key]."\n";
}
```

Comment: I have used this line too :- for ($i = 0, $rowcount = count($_POST);

Comment: Check syntax of `for loop` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: I also used foreach loop but I couldn't get multiple textboxes values..

Comment: Well, the real question here is.. how does your html look like?

Comment: Please provide either the contents of POST `var_dump($_POST):` or the html form, or both

Comment: <input type="radio" name="description[]" value="wet" class="">  and <input type="text" name="timepicker[]" id="" class="timepicker" > ( I want to add that textboxes value

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/1010970/3128823 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314581/3128823

Comment: I want to get  multiple textboxes value by loop.

Comment: According to your link I used this one too but I couldn't get all description values : foreach( $timepicker as $key => $n ) { print "".$n." ".$description[$key]."\n"; }

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for ($i = 0, $i<= count($_POST['timepicker']); $i++){
echo $timep=$_POST['timepicker'][$i]."<br>";
echo $name = $_POST['fullname'][$i]."<br>"; // get name
echo $job  = $_POST['description'][$i]."<br>"; // get jobtitle
}

?>
```

Comment: the above code will loop for each values of count of form object.

Comment: try print_r($job) to check description values outside the loop

Comment: foreach( $timepicker as $key => $n ) { print "".$n." ".$description[$key]."\n"; } I used this one too but I couldn't get all description values

Comment: Check my newly upgraded code : for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST); $i++) {
echo $_POST['timepicker'][$i]."\n";
echo $_POST['description'][$i]."\n";
}

Comment: foreach( $timepicker as $key => $n ) {
print "".$n." ".$discription[$key]."\n";
}

Comment: check your form object whether the name attribute is specified correctly with array for example name='description[]'

Comment: $timepicker = $_POST['timepicker']; 
$discription = $_POST['description'];
foreach( $timepicker as $key => $n ) 
{
print "".$n." ".$discription[$key]."\n";
}

Comment: replace $timepicker with $discription  in your foreach loop

Comment: please check my edited answer , you will get values.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $discription as $value) 
{
print $value."\n";
}
```

Comment: I want to get both two values by foreach  timepicker and description

Answer (score 0):

The correct Answer is :-

```
   foreach( $discription as $value) 
   {
   print $value."\n";
   }
```