# How does this code to create an array in HTML accessed by PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I was going through Head First PHP and came by this piece of code.

```
<?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'atlantis2016', 'elvis_store')
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      foreach ($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id) 
      {
        $query = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE id = $delete_id";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
      }
      echo 'Customer removed. <br />';
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
      echo $row['first_name'];
      echo ' ' . $row['last_name'];
      echo ' ' . $row['email'];
      echo '<br />';
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I fully understand how we go through all the ids present in the array `todelete` by using the foreach loop.

What I don't get is how the array itself is created? Are there even arrays in HTML? IF not, how are we creating a PHP array using pure HTML in the following line?

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
```

Additionally, what I also find mysterious is how only those *id*'s for which the checkboxes have been ticked end up in the array `todelete` while the others are ignored?

Basically, explain the origin and functioning of the `todelete` array for me, please.

Comment: This is an FAQ on the PHP site :) Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays  Let us know if you need clarifications.

Comment: @ymas So let me get this right.. while todelete[] itself is not an array in HTML,but by the virtue of the `[]` after the name, the php script acting on it convert and creates an array called todelete. Is that correct?

Also, why only certain values which are the ones of the checkboxes that have been ticked make its way into the todelete array?

Comment: Checkboxes aren't submitted as part of the request if they aren't checked, so only the ones that have been selected end up in the PHP array. And yes, you're correct on the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the input name as `todelete[]`, we are saying that this input  variable `todelete` will send any selected checkboxes upon form submission to a PHP script by `POST` or `GET`.

The PHP script defined in the parent form `'action'` attribute will be able to access values under `$_REQUEST['todelete']` which will be an array structure.

This syntax is useful if we want to send multiple values associated to a variable name.

See also: [HTML input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

The top rated answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays) link describes the inner workings of the array beautifully. It cleared up almost all of my doubts.