# Inputs array from while loop, passing $_POST for each input

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, prepared-statement

```
<form role="form" autocomplete="off" action="includes/functions/fisa-init.php" method="POST">
<?php
   connectDB();
   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `optionale`") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   { 
?>
   <span><?php echo $row['denumire']; ?></span>
   <input type="text" name="nrBucati[]">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['cod']; ?>" name="codProdus[]">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

In the while loop I get an array for `input name="nrBucati[]"` and `input name="codProdus[]"`.

I have the query:

```
$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("
            UPDATE 
            `stocuri` 
            SET 
            `cantitate` = `cantitate` - ?
            WHERE `cod` = ?
            ");


    $stmt3->bind_param("is", $bucata, $cod);

    // set parameters and execute
    foreach( $_POST['nrBucati'] as $bucata ) {
    return $bucata; 
    }

    foreach( $_POST['codProdus'] as $cod ) {
    return $cod;
    }

    if (!$stmt3->execute()) 
        {
            echo "Execuția a întâmpinat o eroare: (" . $stmt3->errno . ") " . $stmt3->error;
        }
    $stmt3->close();
```

I cannot manage to take all the input array values through `$_POST`. Detailed in:

[While loop - Only one input from many others is sending a value through POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349889/while-loop-only-one-input-from-many-others-is-sending-a-value-through-post)

How to get each input value from the arrays `nrBucati[]` and `codProdus[]` from HTML, through POST?

Comment: I think I need to combine the 2 foreach into one and execute the query inside it.

Comment: Why are your input names arrays?  You should only use that for checkbox type inputs where you can have multiple possible values per 1 input name.  For text/hidden fields you should just use a string.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but you can't use the `return` keyword to return multiple values from a loop....

Comment: If I do not use arrays for names, I will get only one input value, instead off all. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349889/while-loop-only-one-input-from-many-others-is-sending-a-value-through-post

Comment: @EatPeanutButter You are right. I realise now.

Comment: @RyanTuosto I have multiple possible values per 1 input name there.

Comment: returns are usually for classes and/or methods in a case like this; are you using any?

Comment: Anyway, I should use an implode or foreach in the same time on both arrays because the query need both. But not sure how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this to properly assign/pair up your two params and then execute your query call from within the loop.

```
foreach( $_POST['nrBucati'] as $id => $bucata ) {
    $cod = $_POST['codProdus'][$id];

    if (!$stmt3->execute()) 
        {
            echo "Execuția a întâmpinat o eroare: (" . $stmt3->errno . ") " . $stmt3->error;
        }
}
```

Comment: LOL. Worked like charm!!!! You saved my ass! I love you man. Thanks for understanding my poor explanations!

Comment: I knew I had to combine those 2 params somehow but no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Run a `foreach` and prepare your data inside `foreach` loop:

```
// Get posted data and execute
foreach( $_POST['nrBucati'] as $key=>$bucata ) {
    $cod = $_POST['codProdus'][$key]; // For object change this to $_POST['codProdus']->$key;

    $stmt3= $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `stocuri` SET `cantitate` = `cantitate` - ? 
                              WHERE `cod` = ? ");
    $stmt3->bind_param("is", $bucata, $cod);

    if (!$stmt3->execute()){

        echo "Execuția a întâmpinat o eroare: (" . $stmt3->errno . ") " . $stmt3->error;
    }

    $stmt3->close();

}
```