# store php variables from appended form data in the form of an array

Tags: javascript, php, append

I have created a php form which appends new text variables like this:

```
<form action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data” method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">

    <div id="div">
        value <input type="text" name="tst" >
     <button onclick ="appendRow()" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
     <input type="submit" value="test" name="submit" >
     </div>
</form>
```

I have added the following java script to it:

```
<script> 
    var x=1
function appendRow()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('div');
   d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='tst"+ x++ +"'><br >";
}
</script>
```

Now I want to store all the variables I get from the form and use them for further calculations. I tried the for each loop for that:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && is_array($_POST['submit'] == "test")) {
    foreach($_POST["submit"] as $key => $tst){
        $capture_field_vals .= $tst .", ";
    }
    echo $capture_field_vals;
```

But nothing is happening. Can you please tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: Is your form's method `POST`?

Comment: Is your inputs wrapped with a `<form>` element?

Comment: yes @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: Check the form tag and the form action.

Comment: @RachelWatson Update your question and include the form element.

Comment: check the method is post too

Comment: do `var_dump($_POST)` and see the structure of your incoming data.  I think you will see whats wrong

Comment: I would suggest completely removing `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"` and `action=""`.

Comment: I'm also fairly sure `is_array($_POST['submit'] == "test")` is invalid.

Comment: Don't loop over `$_POST["submit"]` but loop over `$_POST`. And `$_POST["submit"]` is not an array but a value, use `is_array($_POST) === true`

Comment: yeah, I agree with GrumpyCrouton.  It seems like OP thinks $_POST['submit'] is how to access the posted data, but it is really just the button value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `action` properties from your form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Having multiple form actions is not supported, and forms will post to the same page they were submitted to if no action is given (by default).

Next, submit your form `name='tst'` as an array, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="tst[]"/>
```

And in you JavaScript, do the same:

```
d.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="tst[]"/><br>';
```

(You do not need the `x` variable), ([`input arrays`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays))

Now, in your PHP you can loop through all of the submitted `tst` values.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['tst'] as $tst){
        $capture_field_vals .= $tst .", ";
    }
    echo rtrim($capture_field_vals, ','); //rtrim will remove trailing comma
}
```

([`rtrim()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php))

But this can be simplified even more with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo implode(', ', $_POST['tst']);
}
```

Comment: @RachelWatson Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems wrong. There's nothing to loop through with `$_POST['submit']`, it's just a single value. The actual array is `$_POST`.

```
foreach($_POST["submit"] as $key => $tst){
        $capture_field_vals .= $tst .", ";
    }
```

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $tst){
        $capture_field_vals .= $tst .", ";
    }
```