# PHP doesn't see new elements created with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I faced an issue since I can't get a just created element with a PHP script.

I have a list of tags loaded with PHP:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="4">
    Some tag
  <li>
<ul>
```

Thanks to AJAX I append another element inside the UL

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.add-tag-btn').click(function(event) {
    var tag_title = $('.tag-search').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'add-tag.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'tag_title': tag_title
      },
      success:function(result){
        $('.tag-search').val('');
        $('.new-tags').append('<li><input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="'+result.tag_id+'">'+tag_title+'</li>');

        console.log(result.tag_id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Thus I have a new UL

```html
<ul>
  <li><input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="4">Value #4</li>
  <li><input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="5">Value #5 (new value generated with jQuery and AJAX)</li>
</ul>
```

But once I submit the form, only the existed value is added to DB.

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ....
    bla bla bla
    foreach ($_POST['check_list_tags'] as $value) {
        $arr2[] = $value;
        }
    bla bla bal
}
```

Looks like that PHP can't handle a new value without the page reloaded. At the same time, I add

```js
checked="checked"
```

dynamically and that works just perfect.

Can anyone explain me how to force PHP to see the newly created elements (the elements that were appended to the existed HTML by the means of jQuery).

Thanks everyone for the assistance.

upd:

This is how I add the "checked"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.adm-checkbox').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

This is how the form looks like:

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo $router->url ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.....
<ul class="new-tags">

</ul>
<ul>
   <?php foreach ($admin->getAdmTags() as $value): ?>
      <li><input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><?php echo $value['title'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<ul>
</form>
```

UPD # 2:

May be the reason is that I use two separate functions in jQuery for "checked"??!?!

```
$('.adm-checkbox').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute("checked");
    }
  });
```

and

```
$('.adm-tags').on('click', '.adm-checkbox', function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute("checked");
    }
  });
```

I do it because onclick doesn't work for the newly created elements.

P.s: It doesn't matter where I put a newly created "li"...

**Thank everyone for participation. I've created a new page and did everything again. And now it works. Now I need to find the mistake in my full code.**

Comment: Did you add the checked="checked" or checked="true" ?

Comment: <input class="adm-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="6"> It's working now. when you add the element dynamically, you should have the checked option or let you click on checkbox. and then let you test it and let me know.

Comment: <input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="89" checked="checked">

Comment: if you checked on the checkbox manually, does it work ?

Comment: PHP does not know how an element is created. What have you tried to check for differences in the markup?

Comment: Everything work perfectly. I click the checkbox on a newly created element and jQuery add checked="checked". But when I submit the form only previously created tags are added to the database

Comment: Forget about PHP/databases - this question has nothing to do with them, and everything to do with whiche form inputs are used in building the post data. You can check for the presence/absence of the problem simply by looking in the dev tools network log when the form is submitted.

Comment: Utkanos, I don't see anything in the dev tools network tab.

Comment: Then the filter options in the network console aren't showing XHR requests.

Answer (score 0):

Name attributes can be arrays so the name isn't the issue - [HTML input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)

I think the reason is as you mentioned, the `checked` attribute needs to be added to all of the inputs otherwise the value won't be sent in the request.

If the inputs were text or number for example, then the `checked` attribute wouldn't be needed.

The same would apply to radio inputs, or the `selected` attribute for a select menu.

TLDR, add `checked`:

```
$('.new-tags').append('<li><input class="adm-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_list_tags[]" value="'+result.tag_id+'" checked>'+tag_title+'</li>');
```

That is of course, if it should be automatically checked and not reliant on the user checking it manually.

I may have to change this answer based on if this is a traditional form submission or an ajax submission not using a form.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether I add checked="checked" by the means of jQuery or add the checkbox manually, when I click the submit button, only the checkbox values that were rendered in the initially created HTML go to my database.

Comment: Everything looks natural and evident, but doesn't work :-(

Comment: could you add more to your question, the form markup and anything else such as, there's no `.new-tags` in your question so where do the dynamically added tags get appended to? My guess would be `new-tags` is a class on the `ul` element but the question doesn't show that.

Comment: Previously I created a new <ul class="new-tags"></ul> and put a newly created <li> element inside it. But I've been trying to add the new <li> inside the old <ul>. But still it doesn't work. I feel that the solution should be simple, but can't define it.

Comment: In any case whether it be inside <ul class="new-tags"> or not, the new <li> is inside the <form></form>

Comment: thanks, will take a look with the update, one thing I have noticed is the closing tag is missing for the first `ul` - not sure if a typo in the question or if it actually exists in your code, just something that might cause issues so worth pointing out.

Comment: Do you do anything else inside your click handlers for the checkboxes? The setting of the checked property will be handled by the browser so you shouldn't need them unless you are doing other things as well. For the even to work with dynamically created checkboxes and to use one listener, use `$(document).on('click', '.adm-checkbox', function() {` instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to close the topic. It works with the newly created code. Once I find out the mistake in my full code, I will reply with the explanation of my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

When you send a form though either POST or GET every input needs a unique name. From you code it looks like you add a new input element with a name attribute that has the same value as the already existing element.

I suspect if you add the new element with a unique name value it should work. You could incorporate that into you JavaScript code by having a counter for the number of input elements with name X and then add a number. And you would need to do a similar thing in your PHP.

**Edit:** Apparently you can have name attributes with the same name if you use '[]' after the name, thank you @martincarlin87

Comment: name values can be the same if they are using the array syntax -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays

Comment: @martincarlin87 Cool didn't know that! Learned something today!